# nuxtjs static site generation with images

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs

If I run `nuxt generate`, then it generates the desired static standalone output in `dist`. However, all image/asset references are not being exported to the `dist` folder as well. Is there a way to achieve this with nuxtjs without a workaround?

Comment: In which folder are your images located ?

Comment: they are hosted at a url, meaning the images are provided from a headless cms. The nuxtjs team told me that there is no such possibility.